# Why is there a missing keyword error?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, foreign-keys, constraints, ora-00905

```
CREATE TABLE SORDER (
    C_NO CHAR(4),
    P_NO CHAR(4),
    QUANTITY SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C_NO, P_NO),
    CONSTRAINT CNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (C_NO) REFERENCES CUSTOMER ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT PNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (P_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCT2 ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

here are the two other tables btw.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT2 (
    P_NO CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    P_NAME CHAR(6),
    PRICES DECIMAL(3,2),
    STOCK SMALLINT
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER2 (
    C_NO CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    C_NAME CHAR(6),
    CITY CHAR(11)
);
```

Comment: Btw: you do **not** want to use `CHAR(n)` use `VARCHAR(n)` instead

Comment: I am also pretty sure that you don't want `decimal(3,2)`. With that the maximum price you can store is 9.99

Answer (score 5):

Oracle only supports `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `ON DELETE CASCADE` as a keyword. The functionality of `ON DELETE RESTRICT` is achieved by leaving out the `ON DELETE`

```
CREATE TABLE SORDER (
    C_NO CHAR(4),
    P_NO CHAR(4),
    QUANTITY SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C_NO, P_NO),
    CONSTRAINT CNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (C_NO) REFERENCES CUSTOMER2,
    CONSTRAINT PNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (P_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCT2
);
```

For details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJABCJJF

Quote from the manual:

> *The ON DELETE clause lets you determine how Oracle Database automatically maintains referential integrity if you remove a referenced primary or unique key value. If you omit this clause, then Oracle does not allow you to delete referenced key values in the parent table that have dependent rows in the child table*

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07e93/1

Comment: Plus the table name is wrong...

Comment: Didnt fully understand you, I leave just restrict ?

Comment: How do I establish then this

Primary key: C_NO + P_NO

Foreign Key: C_NO References Customer table, Restrict on Delete
Foreign Key: P_NO References Product  table, Restrict on Delete

Comment: This is just what the instrucctions are asking me for, its unnecessary the use of the restrict on delete you say? cause its already a PK, is that it?

Comment: @user2082958: sorry, you lost me. I have **no** idea what you are talking about. I showed you the correct `CREATE TABLE` statement that fixes the problem in your question. If you have another question, then don't post this as a comment, create a new question.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935432/how-do-i-create-this-tables-establishngi-a-fk-wih-restrict-on-delete-on-sql

Comment: @user2082958: My answer precisely answers that question. **Again**: you have to leave out the `ON DELETE RESTRICT` in Oracle to achieve exactly that behaviour (do read the part from the manual that I quoted).

Answer (score -6):

Try the below code

```
CREATE TABLE SORDER (
    C_NO CHAR(4),
    P_NO CHAR(4),
    QUANTITY SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C_NO, P_NO),
    CONSTRAINT CNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (C_NO) REFERENCES CUSTOMER ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT PNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (P_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCT2 ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: What is the difference to the original SQL?

Comment: That's exactly the code he tried :)

Comment: try with mine code once.